# RelativeLayout - referencing ids within another nested view - is this possible?

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

Is it possible to do something like this where TV2 is relative to TV1, where TV1 and TV2 are within different branches of the layout?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/RV1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TV01"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:text="test text" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/RV2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/RV1" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TV02"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/TV01"  <--------- this references TV01 within the top RelativeView !!!
            android:text="other text" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

in this example the statement `android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/TV01"` does not seem to work, since `TV01` is within another RealtiveLayout branch than `TV02`.

**Is there a way to somehow make references like this?**

Many thanks!

Comment: Can you post an image of the layout that you are trying to achieve? It is likely that you can achieve it in some way other than the one you are trying (which as you have found won't work).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you cannot use RelativeLayout positioning like that. However:

- You can combine `RV1` and `RV2`

or

- You can position `RV2` to the right of `RV1`

Comment: thanks - I was hoping for some kind of "path" that one could provide when defining the dependency - xml is just too restrictive....:-(

Answer (score 1):

Is this a simplified example? or is this your actual layout. If the latter you should be able to achieve the same effect by changing rel2 to be like this:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/RV2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/RV1"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/RV1" >
```

Comment: Did you mean to keep the `layout_below` attribute? Won't this position `RV2` to the lower-right of `RV1` (on the diagonal)?

Comment: It will put RV2 below and to the right of RV1, so it will be like down and right catty corner. Based on his code that seems to me like what he is trying to do. Tough to say for sure though without more clarification.

Comment: actually it was meant as a simplified example, thanks for the answer though. Finally it looks as if one cannot reference inside another RV...