# How to align view (like in RelativeLayout) with a nephew view?

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

[Related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11493693/1034042). Answer: RelativeLayout can't do it. I'm asking how to do it anyway, with not *just* RL, or with something else.

General story: you have a complex layout that would be difficult to adjust, and along comes a request for something to be added, aligning with a nested view.
[image]

What is the best approach? A popup with a custom style? (not familiar with those yet)? Spending days changing the whole hierarchy to a single `RelativeLayout`? A custom Layout class as wrapper?
`AbsoluteLayout` (deprecated) or FrameLayout with programmatically changed `LayoutParams` or margins? (this I'd rather avoid, I prefer not to touch onMeasure, etc)

Simplified example (no relation to pic above):
LinearLayout defines relative heights of the elements. I don't know to do it with RelativeLayout.
`anExpandableView` is something to be animated as sliding from under `someBar` (here; full-width, but perhaps it may need to align its width, as well as vertical position).

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <include
            android:id="@+id/topStuff"
            layout="@layout/incl_topstuff"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="7"
            android:layout_height="0dip" />

        <include
            android:id="@+id/someBar"
            layout="@layout/incl_filters_and_stuff"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <include
            android:id="@+id/bottomStuff"
            layout="@layout/incl_bottomstuff"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="10" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <include
        android:id="@+id/anExpandableView"
        layout="@layout/incl_filters"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:layout_below="@id/someBar"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I know SO has an aversion to general questions, but I don't want an ad-hoc solution. I am asking what to do in cases which would be solved if only a wrapping `RelativeLayout` would allow alignment to a view that is not a direct sibling.

Comment: Perhaps you could provide a graphical diagram of what you want your view to look like...

Comment: I knew it, a demand for a specific case. No, I refuse. I want to do the equivalent of `layout_alignBottom` or `layout_below`, etc, referencing not a sibling view but something nested deeper. I used `include` because it does not matter what the views are, only what `anExpandableView` needs to position itself. If you have trouble understanding, please point to the unclear part.

Comment: The first sentence itself is already very cryptive `you have a complex layout and along comes a request for something to be added, aligning with a nested view.`. What do you mean by Complex Layout? A view could be considered nested or not depending on they layout it uses... hence without the proper context, it's hard to understand the question. If "a" graphical diagram would get us to give you a rigid answer, perhaps you could provide 2 or more diagrams to describe the general idea.

Comment: The important thing is that it does not matter. O.K. Example task: *Add NewView below- and width-aligned with view Vk*. If Views V0..Vn are all direct children of 1 RelativeLayout, the task is simple. If, however, Vk is a child of Vj (which is, e.g., a LinearLayout inside the RelativeLayout), then we have the situation I am talking about. "A complex layout" is one that works and I don't know how to turn into a single RL. Nesting means "inside another view inside that one".

Comment: Image illustrating the idea added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting it simply, RelativeLayout can only measure and layout it's direct children based on each other, but I guess you already knew that.

The only general solution would be to implement your own custom Layout class, which I wouldn't recommend. If I had to guess why RelativeLayout does not traverse the entire layout hierarchy at it's level and below, it's probably for performance reasons.

Unfortunately if you're using RelativeLayouts and LinearLayouts and you want views to be dependent on each other you have to pick one approach and stick to it, either the flat hierarchy of RelativeLayout, or the nested one of LinearLayout.

Based on your example, as far as I know, there is no way to implement weighted views with a RelativeLayout, so you're stuck with using a LinearLayout.

The easiest way to do what you want is to inflate your expandableView in code, align it with the bottom of the RelativeLayout, set it's height and position based on bottomStuff, and animate from there.

If you really want to do it in xml, I can think of one somewhat hacky, ad-hoc approach, but which can can be generalized to mirroring the measurement and layout of any hierarchy with a bit of work.

Create a parallel but invisible LinearLayout that is a sibling of the first one. Give it an empty view with weight 7 on top, an invisible copy of someBar in the middle, then your expandable view under that with weight 10. To have it slide up, either animate the height of the invisible someBar and the weight of the empty view on top towards 0, or remove them/set them to gone and set animateLayoutChanges on your LinearLayout.

Comment: Thank you. Re: "picking one approach" - `LinearLayout` can't align. `RelativeLayout` can't do weights. I need a bit of both. For now, I make the view "gone", and programmatically set margins. Do you know a better way of getting a view's coordinates than recursively adding values of `getTop()` of the view and every ancestor?

Comment: btw, I don't think performance was the reason. findViewByID is done very frequently, and I have yet to see anyone care about optimizing it. More likely it was to avoid circular references.

Comment: You can use View.getGlobalVisibleRect and offset it from the parent view you want coordinates relative to, or get the size of the view from the rect, rather than recursively adding relative offsets. Then set the height and width via RelativeLayout.LayoutParams. I'm not sure why you would want to set margins and not set the height or position directly.

Specifically, use View.getGlobalVisibleRect on bottomStuff, get the height from the rect top and bottom, and set that to the height of your expandableView, with expandableView set to alignParentBottom.

Comment: By the way just a note about the original question, in your specific example the reason you can't do what you want easily is only because you want to animate it. If you just want to solve the general problem you're describing above including your diagram, it is almost always enough to just use the typical nested structure, and nest the dependent view inside your LinearLayout. It's only because your view changes to grow outside of the LinearLayout that you can't nest it inside.

Comment: also to your comment about findViewById, it is not as cheap as you think, the view holder pattern exists to optimize redundant calls to it, and it is not used internally in RelativeLayout or LinearLayout. I just checked the source.

Comment: Thank you. Yeah, `getGlobalVisibleRect` sounds better. Too bad I still have to wait for the rest of the layout to ... be laid out. Too much of that happening already...